# How many bank tiers are there?

Tags: banking, terminology

One can often see bank tiers 1-3 being mentioned, yet sometimes there are also  tiers 4 to 6.

So, how many bank tiers are there really?

Comment: Can you add an example of where you saw that mentioned?

Comment: How does this question help you with your personal finances?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a reference that seems to cover it, at least for Gartner: https://www.gartner.com/it-glossary/bank-tier

> Bank tier or size — that is, the size of the bank in relation to other
>   banks — depends  on the relative size to the overall banking market in
>   terms of total banking assets as provided by the balance sheet of the
>   bank. This type of comparison – across tiers – makes sense in relation
>   to a particular country or region that define that specific banking
>   marketplace. For this reason Gartner has preferred to adopt a
>   localized definition of bank tiers that depends on 11 different
>   regions that cluster together countries of similar economic and
>   business homogeneity and avoid a generic global definition of bank
>   tiers that would not allow proper comparison between the largest banks
>   of different regions.

Investopedia references bank tiers, https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/043015/what-difference-between-tier-1-capital-and-tier-2-capital.asp, but they are internal to the bank itself.

> Under the Basel Accord, a bank's capital consists of tier 1 capital
>   and tier 2 capital, and the two types of capital are different. Tier 1
>   capital is a bank's core capital, whereas tier 2 capital is a bank's
>   supplementary capital. A bank's total capital is calculated by adding
>   its tier 1 and tier 2 capital together. Regulators use the capital
>   ratio to determine and rank a bank's capital adequacy

Comment: I was tempted to downvote this answer.. Tier 1-2 capital has nothing to do with the question. From the question, this refers to bank sizes / reputability.

Comment: The question didn't specify context. I provided two contexts. If there is a third or specific context please make an edit.